# numpy how to change an array into a zero one except the max value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to make a function that when fed an array, it returns an array of the same shape but with all zeros expect for 1 value that is the max one. eg. with an array like this:

```
my_array = np.arange(9).reshape((3,3))

[[ 0.  1.  2.]
 [ 3.  4.  5.]
 [ 6.  7.  8.]]
```

when passed in the function I want it out like this:

```
[[ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  8.]]
```

exeption:

When there is many max value that are equal, I only want one out of them and the rest gets zero'ed out (the order doesn't matter).

I am honeslty clueless as to how to make this in an elegant way that is furthermore efficient, how would you do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For efficiency, use `array-initialization` and `argmax` to get the max index (first one linearly indexed if more than one) -

```
def app_flat(my_array):
    out = np.zeros_like(my_array)
    idx  = my_array.argmax()
    out.flat[idx] = my_array.flat[idx]
    return out
```

We can also use `ndarray.ravel()` in place of `ndaarray.flat` and I would think that the performance numbers would be comparable.

For this sparsey output, to gain memory efficiency and hence performance, you might want to use `sparse` matrices, especially for large arrays. Thus, for sparse matrix output, we would have an alternative one, like so -

```
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix

def app_sparse(my_array):
    idx  = my_array.argmax()
    r,c = np.unravel_index(idx, my_array.shape)
    return coo_matrix(([my_array[r,c]],([r],[c])),shape=my_array.shape)
```

Sample run -

```
In [336]: my_array
Out[336]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [8, 7, 8]])

In [337]: app_flat(my_array)
Out[337]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [8, 0, 0]])

In [338]: app_sparse(my_array)
Out[338]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 1 stored elements in COOrdinate format>

In [339]: app_sparse(my_array).toarray() # just to confirm values
Out[339]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [8, 0, 0]])
```

Runtime test on bigger array -

```
In [340]: my_array =  np.random.randint(0,1000,(5000,5000))

In [341]: %timeit app_flat(my_array)
10 loops, best of 3: 34.9 ms per loop

In [342]: %timeit app_sparse(my_array) # sparse matrix output
100 loops, best of 3: 17.2 ms per loop
```

Comment: `ravel` makes a copy if the strides don't work out for a flat view, so `flat` is probably better here.

Answer (score 0):

with few lines:

```
my_array = np.arange(9).reshape((3,3))
my_array2 = np.zeros(len(my_array.ravel()))
my_array2[np.argmax(my_array)] = np.max(my_array)
my_array2 = my_array2.reshape(my_array.shape)
```